# Combining date and time into datetime for a large number of xml files in a staging table at one go for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datetime

I am new at this so please bear with me. I have managed to take hundreds of xml documents and put them into a staging table via a single query. Looking at my data I realize that I would like it if my action-date and action-time columns were merged into a single column I will call datetime (containing datetime data type). How would I accomplish this considering that I want to do it all in one go? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Here is my query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[staagingTable]
(
    [Counter] INT NOT NULL,
    [majority] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [congress] [int] NULL,
    [session] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [chamber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [rollcall-num] [int] NULL,
    [legis-num] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-question] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-type] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-result] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [action-date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [action-time] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-desc] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [sourceXML] [XML] NULL
);
GO

DECLARE @Counter INT=1;
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE @Counter<800
BEGIN
    SET @command=
    '
DECLARE @xmlString VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''C:\Users\Owner\Documents\congress\House votes\114 congress 2015\Passage\roll' + REPLACE(STR(@Counter,3),' ','0') + '.xml'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS c
    );

    SET @xmlString=SUBSTRING(@xmlString,CHARINDEX(''<rollcall-vote>'',@xmlString,1),9999999);

    DECLARE @xml XML=CAST(@xmlString AS XML);

    INSERT INTO dbo.staagingTable(Counter, majority, congress,[session], chamber, [rollcall-num], [legis-num], [vote-question], [vote-type], [vote-result], [action-date], [action-time], [vote-desc], [sourceXML])
        SELECT 
            ' +  CAST(@Counter AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',
            v.value(N''majority[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''congress[1]'', N''int''),
            v.value(N''session[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''chamber[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''rollcall-num[1]'', N''int''),
            v.value(N''legis-num[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''), 
            v.value(N''vote-question[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''vote-type[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''vote-result[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''action-date[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''action-time[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''vote-desc[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            @xml
        FROM 
            @xml.nodes(N''/rollcall-vote/vote-metadata'') AS A(v);
    ';

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@command);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH;

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.staagingTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.staagingTable;
```

Here is a screenshot of the table my query yielded. The two columns I want to combine into one have purple symbols drawn above them.

[image: muh screenshot]

Here is a baby version of one of my xml documents.

```
<rollcall-vote>
  <vote-metadata>
    <majority>R</majority>
    <congress>114</congress>
    <session>1st</session>
    <chamber>U.S. House of Representatives</chamber>
    <rollcall-num>6</rollcall-num>
    <legis-num>H RES 5</legis-num>
    <vote-question>On Agreeing to the Resolution</vote-question>
    <vote-type>YEA-AND-NAY</vote-type>
    <vote-result>Passed</vote-result>
    <action-date>6-Jan-2015</action-date>
    <action-time time-etz="17:30">5:30 PM</action-time>
    <vote-desc>Adopting rules for the One Hundred Fourteenth Congress</vote-desc>
  </vote-metadata>
</rollcall-vote>
```

**UPDATE**

As per Cam Bruce's suggestion I made the changes seen in the screenshot below, which also contains the accompanying error.

[image: screenshot]

**ATTEMPT #2**

[image: attempt 2]

**ATTEMPT #3**

[image: screenshoot]

**ATTEMPT #4**

[image: with error]

**ATTEMPT**

This attempt is using Shnugo's suggestion. The two columns were merged but they seem to be the columns from the dummy values and not my table.

[image: ye boi]

**ATTEMPT 2**

[image: attmpt]

**attempt 3**

[image: my code]

Comment: Your code should 1) create a statement to read **one** xml file, 2) execute it 3) do this over and over and 4) **after the loop** it should add the `DateCombined` column and update its value. What you are doing in *attempt 3* is to add the column and run the `UPDATE` command **before** inserting any row...

Comment: @Shnugo Ok. Let me try this step by step. What would a statement to read one xml file look like? Your instructions leave me feeling very lost.

Comment: Sorry, do you really mean what you ask? In your last questions I invested hours to help you through this! **You are reading your XMLs succesfully already**. At the end of your existing code there is `SELECT * FROM dbo.staagingTable;` and I assume, that you see your data here. Correct? You question is not at all related to `xml`, nor is it related to `C#` nor is the posted code of any relevance! Your question is *After some import my staging table contains this data (add **copy'n'pasteable data here**). How can I combine `action-date` and `action-time` to a proper datetime value?*

Comment: Sorry. I do mean what I ask. The terminology you use is unfamiliar to me. I do not have any formal training in sql. I have never programmed before. I am completely new at this but right now my life situation demands that I make this database. I spend all my waking hours on this project. I need to see exactly what the query should look like. That is the only way I can learn. It is the only way I can apply what you show me to my future work. Right now all I'm doing is shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all the reading process from XML into your staging table is successfully done. Now you want to combine these two columns to a typed `DATETIME` (good idea!)

*btw: For your next question: Try to avoid posting irrelevant code...*

Unfortunately the used format is really bad (culture and language dependant!) and is [not matching one of the pre-defined ones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Try it like this:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;

--Some dummy values for testing

DECLARE @Dummy TABLE([action-date] NVARCHAR(MAX),[action-time] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
 ('6-Jan-2015','5:30 PM')
,('8-Jan-2015','2:10 PM')
,('22-Jan-2015','11:04 AM')
,('10-Mar-2015','00:00 AM');

--The existing [action-date] can be converted with code "106". In order to allow  
--the usage of your time format I first combine them on string level and then  
--re-convert them to `DATETIME` using format "100"

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CONVERT(DATETIME,d.[action-date],106),100)+ ' ' + d.[action-time],100)
FROM @Dummy AS d
```

The result

```
2015-01-06 17:30:00.000
2015-01-08 14:10:00.000
2015-01-22 11:04:00.000
2015-03-10 00:00:00.000
```

### UPDATE How to use this with your project

When your reading is done, complete and ready all your former XML data is now within your table `dbo.staagingTable`.

Try this to first add a new column and then use my code to set its value

There's a final `SELECT` to check the result. Very simple...

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[staagingTable] ADD CombinedDate DATETIME NULL;
GO
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
UPDATE [dbo].[staagingTable] 
SET CombinedDate=CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CONVERT(DATETIME,[action-date],106),100)+ ' ' + [action-time],100);

SELECT [action-date],[action-time],CombinedDate
FROM [dbo].[staagingTable];
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.staagingTable
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. You can see it in my edits. In the future I will try to include only the code I think that people need to help me. I can always add more of my code if they request it.

Comment: @anang No you've got this wrong completely! I mean: Read the data into the staging table as you did it before. Now you can use the code above with the columns of your **staagingTable**. The table `@Dummy` is only to create a *stand-alone* working example... You do not need this at all!

Comment: I have posted my next attempt.

Comment: Upon doing this I receive an error saying combineddate is an invalid column name. That seems strange to me. Doesn't the ALTER TABLE line add that column in?

Comment: Also how does someone read data into their staging table? Where in the query does that happen.

Comment: I modified the code in my update section. Please check again

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. You state at the beginning of your question *I have managed to take hundreds of xml documents and put them into a staging table via a single query*. From this I take, that the XML-reading is successfully finished and all data is in your staging table. Correct?

Comment: Well it was in staging table and I still have the necessary query to do that. But whenever I alter that query to make the datetime column I encounter problems.

Comment: *I encounter problems* is not very specific... If the column is there already, you should not use the `ALTER` command. Just use the `UPDATE` and check with the `SELECT`.

Comment: I have posted an edit to show where I am right now in attempting to follow your instructions.

Comment: @anang Well, I place my comment here to get it in the right context: Just take your original code. Your steps: 1) **DROP** the existing staging table (if it exists) 2) Replace your last line `DROP TABLE dbo.staagingTable;` with my code from above (`ALTER TABLE ...` down to the last `GO`). 3) Let the final `DROP` away in order to keep the data after your import. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date and time strings are all the same format as in your screenshot, you can concatenate them using the xquery `concat()` function:

```
v.value(N''concat(action-date[1], concat('''' '''', action-time[1]))'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
```

Comment: Please see my newest update. I'm pretty sure I applied your suggestion incorrectly.

Comment: the `concat()` function is a function of xquery, so it needs to be inside the literal quotes in the xquery expression, where you are referencing `action-time[1]`, etc.

Comment: so it needs to be one long string literal: `'concat(action-date[1], concat('' '', action-time[1]))'`

Comment: I have taken a screenshot of my second attempt. I am having a hard time understanding some of the phrases you are using. Like I said I am quite new at this. If I could have more encompassing illustrations along with your explanation it could help me understand what you are saying.

Comment: you almost have it, looks like a copy paste error. essentially when you are calling `v.value(expression, datatype)`, that is evaluating an xquery expression and converting it to the specified sql dataype, which usually is just the attribute name, such as `action-time[1]`, but in this case, we're using multiple `concat()` functions as well, to get the value that we need

Comment: so, you just need the two `concat()` expressions, as listed in my original answer. so a) the `action-date[1]` at the end of the expression is not needed, so remove it. b)  change `nvarchar(max)` to `datetime`

Comment: Am I getting warmer?

Comment: are you getting an error message? change `nvarchar(max)` to `datetime`

Comment: I have made your most recently suggested change and now have a screenshot of it including the error

Comment: @CamBruce If I get this correctly, it would be better not to include this complex conversions into the reading process. OP said, that all the data is taken into the staging table. So I would continue with this... A staging table should be very tolerant and accept *everything*.  Validations, conversions etc. should be done when the data in pushed into the final tables... Just my 2c

Comment: Bingo! It worked. I just have a question though. The data type for this concat is nvarchar right? Do you think it might be better for me if it was datetime instead? I feel like I might want to compare different tables in the future depending on the date and time that the event depicted in the table occurs. Will that work with an nvarchar type? It will be important for me to compare when the various events occur in relation to each other.

Comment: great! if you know that the data quality of your xml, then you should definitely convert it to datetime, but hold off if it isn't

Answer (score -1):

Create a datetime field in the [dbo].[staagingTable]

and modify the insert query for that new field and populate it with 
CONVERT(datetime,'action-date[1]'+' '+action-time[1] , 100)

Comment: that's not going to work without the using xquery `value` function, as referenced in the op